# Placing an object on right position (Java)

Tags: java

I have a simple test that looks like

```
public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Board b1 = new Board();
        Knight bk = new Knight(Player.BLACK);
        b1.placePiece(0, 0, bk);
        System.out.println(b1.getPiece(0, 0));


    }

}
```

And this is supposed to print out "bk" since that is placed on (0, 0) of Board b1. But it returns null in reality.

My Board class looks like this:

the getPiece should return the piece on board[x][y] but of course it won't since there is nothing on board[x][y]. I know what's wrong, but I am not sure how to fix this.

My Piece class looks like:

```
public abstract class Piece {

    Player color;
    int x, y;

    Piece(Player color){
        this.color = color;

    }

...

}
```

So, I am not sure how to make it possible to have board[x][y] a correct value which is the right Piece object.

EDIT:

EDIT2:

```
public class Board {


....

}
```

Comment: can you show us the code for your `placePiece` method?

Comment: and how you initialize Board.board

Comment: Sorry I missed that. Edited!

Comment: @IddoE Are you talking about the constructor for Board? I did not add that.

Comment: @user6792790 in class Board, do you initialize board ? board = new Piece[rows][cols] ?

Comment: @IddoE Actually, no. Is that something that I have to add?

Comment: @user6792790 yeah you should add that

Comment: Could you check my edit2 please? Is that how I should initialize the board?

Comment: that should work

Comment: @user6792790 yes, you should consider make Board class to singleton (depend on your app) and lazy init inside c'tor

Comment: Utterly pedantic tangent to your question:  A knight in chess is typically abbreviated "N".  This reserves "K" for the king.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize Board

```
board = new Piece[rows][cols]
```

Consider do that inside the constructor

Update:

To get name you should add member name to Piece class

```
abstract class Piece {

        java.awt.Color color;
        String name;
        int x, y;

        Piece(java.awt.Color color, String name) {
            this.color = color;
            this.name = name;

        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Piece{" +
                    "color=" + color +
                    ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", x=" + x +
                    ", y=" + y +
                    '}';
        }
    }

class Knight extends Piece {

        Knight(Color color, String name) {
            super(color, name);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            Knight that = (Knight) obj;
            return this.color == that.color && this.name.equals(that.name);
        }
    }
```

Overriding string will cause

```
System.out.println(new Knight(Color.BLACK, "Robin Hood"));
```

to print

```
Piece{color=java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0], name='Robin Hood', x=0, y=0}
```

Comment: Thanks, but return board[x][y]; on the getPiece method does not actually return the name of the object. How can I actually make it return the name of the object?

Comment: @user6792790 hmm.. what do you mean by "name of the object" ? it returns the object's reference

Comment: @user6792790 returning the name of the variable is not really something you can do in java

Comment: you want it to return "bk"?

Comment: So when I did Knight bk = new Knight(Player.BLACK); and getPiece, I wanted it to actually return bk.

Comment: The problem here is, when doing `Knight bk = new Knight(Player.BLACK);` you create a new `Piece` object. You can reference to that by using bk, That is only a pointer to that object, the object does not that name itself.

Comment: you should extend class Piece and add member "String name" and set name, it can be done by "hack" with "getDeclaredField" which is not good in this situation

Comment: I see. So we can just check if getPiece == bk in this case and it will return True right?

Comment: you should `.equals()` instead of `==`. But it should work

Comment: "==" will work after overriding equals according to your needs (edited my answer, please take a look)